# Slicing a NumPy array with another set of arrays having beginning and ending set of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, indexing

I am writing a code to simulate Continuous Time Random Walk phenomena with a function in python. My code works correctly so far, but I would like to exploit the indexing abilities of NumPy arrays and improve the speed. In the code, below I am generating an ensemble of trajectories, so I have to loop over each of them while generating it. Is it somehow possible to index the NumPy array `x` in such a way that I can get rid of the loop on Nens (the `for` loop in the below code snippet)

```py
    for k in range(Nens):
            
        #start building the trajectory
        stop = 0
        i = 0
        while (stop < Nt):

            #reset the the stop time
            start = stop

            #increment the stop till the next waiting time
            stop += int(trand[i,k]) # A 2D numpy array

   
            #update the trajectory
            x[start:stop,k] = x[start-1,k] \ #x is also a 2D array
                            + (1-int(abs((x[start-1,k]+xrand[i,k])/(xmax))))* xrand[i,k] \
                            - int(abs((x[start-1,k]+xrand[i,k])/(xmax)))*np.sign(x[start-1,k]/xrand[i,k])* xrand[i,k] 
   
            i += 1

    print i
    return T, x
```

A plausible method that I can look to is as follows.

In this code, `start` and `stop` are scalar integers. However, I would like to index this is in way in which both `start` and `stop` are 1D Numpy integer arrays.
But I have seen that if I can use only `stop`/`start` to slice the numpy array, but using slicing from a beginning to ending tuple of indices is not possible .

EDIT 1 (MWE):
The following is the function that I have written, which produces random walk trajectory if given the appropriate parameters,

```py
def ctrw_ens2d(sig,tau,sig2,tau2,alpha,xmax,Nens,Nt=1000,dt=1.0):
    #first define the array for time
    T = np.arange(0,Nt,1)*dt
    
    #generate at least Nt random time increments based on Poisson 
    # distribution (you will use only less than that)
    trand = np.random.exponential(tau, (2*Nt,Nens,1))
    xrand = np.random.normal(0.0,sig,(2*Nt,Nens,2))
    Xdist = np.random.lognormal(-1,0.9,(Nens))
    Xdist = np.clip(Xdist,2*sig,12*sig)
    
    trand2 = np.random.exponential(tau2, (2*Nt,Nens,1))
    xrand2 = np.random.normal(0.0,sig2,(2*Nt,Nens,2))
    
    
    #make a zero array of trajectory
    x1 = np.zeros((Nt,Nens))
    x2 = np.zeros((Nt,Nens))
    y1 = np.zeros((Nt,Nens))
    y2 = np.zeros((Nt,Nens))
    
    for k in range(Nens):
        #start building the trajectory
        stop = 0
        i = 0

        while (stop < Nt):

            #reset the the stop time
            start = stop

            #increment the stop till the next waiting time
            stop += int(trand[i,k,0])           

            #update the trajectory
            r1 = np.sqrt(x1[start-1,k]**2 + y1[start-1,k]**2)
            rr = np.linalg.norm(xrand[i,k])

            x1[start:stop,k] = x1[start-1,k] \
                               + (1-int(abs((r1+rr)/(Xdist[k]))))* xrand[i,k,0] \
                               - int(abs((r1+rr)/(Xdist[k])))* \
                               np.sign(x1[start-1,k]/xrand[i,k,0])* xrand[i,k,0] 
            
            y1[start:stop,k] = y1[start-1,k] \
                                 + (1-int(abs((r1+rr)/(Xdist[k]))))* xrand[i,k,1] \
                                - int(abs((r1+rr)/(Xdist[k])))* \
                                 np.sign(y1[start-1,k]/xrand[i,k,1])* xrand[i,k,1] 
            i += 1
        
        #randomly add jumps in between, at later stage
    
        stop = 1
        i = 0
        while (stop < Nt):

            #reset the the stop time
            start = stop

            #increment the stop till the next waiting time
            stop += int(trand2[i,k,0])

            #update the trajectory
            x2[start:stop,k] = x2[start-1,k] + xrand2[i,k,0]
            y2[start:stop,k] = y2[start-1,k] + xrand2[i,k,1]
            i += 1

        
    return T, (x1+x2), (y1+y2)
```

A simple run of the above function is given below,

```py
    Tmin = 0.61 # in ps
    Tmax = 1000 # in ps
    NT = int(Tmax/Tmin)*10
    delt = (Tmax-0.0)/NT
    print "Delta T, No. of timesteps:",delt,NT
    
    Dint = 0.21 #give it Ang^2/ps
    sig = 0.3 #in Ang
    xmax = 5.*sig
    tau = sig**2/(2*Dint)/delt  # from ps, convert it into the required units according to delt
    print "Waiting time for confined motion (in Delta T units)",tau
    
    Dj = 0.03 # in Ang^2/ps
    tau2 = 10 # in ps
    sig2 = np.sqrt(2*Dj*tau2)
    print "Sigma 2:", sig2
    tau2 = tau2/delt
    alpha  = 1
    
    tim, xtall, ytall = ctrw_ens2d(sig,tau,sig2,tau2,alpha,xmax,100,Nt=NT,dt=delt)
```

The generated trajectories can be plotted as follows,

```
    rall = np.stack((xtall,ytall),axis=-1)
    print rall.shape
    print xtall.shape
    print rall[:,99,:].shape
    k = 19
    plt.plot(xtall[:,k],ytall[:,k])
```

[image: Random walk in 2D]

Comment: it appears that the length of each slice can vary?  Then you have use each separately.

Comment: Indeed, that is the main bottleneck in this problem. If not in NumPy, are there other data objects that can aid in this kind of a slicing?

Comment: Not every loop can be NumPy-vectorized. Since your motivation is speed/efficiency, maybe you can try to Numba-compile the loop. You didn't post a MWE so we can't try it out for you.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I have not used Numba so far, please have a look at the MWE that I have added and let me know about it's feasibility.

Comment: You can (and should) try it yourself: `import numba as nb` and decorate functions with `@nb.njit`. Be sure to use `njit`: it's an alias for `jit(nopython=True)`, and compiling with "no Python" is how you get speed. But it's tricky: Numba does not inherently support all Python or NumPy functions; it has to re-implement things for compilation. `@nb.njit` is handy because it'll throw an error if there's something Numba can't compile. So what you would do is try to carve out the part of your function that is `njit`-compatible and test its speed (no guarantees of speedup).

Comment: What are rr and r1.

Comment: @Bob I am sorry for missing out on that part in the code. Have edited the question to add that.

Comment: @user35952 Did you notice that I added an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a zero array, the loop

```py
while stop < Nt:
  start = stop
  stop += randint();
  x[start:stop] = x[start-1] + rand();
```

will create a series of steps.
A step can be achieved with the cumulative sum of the inpulse

```py
while stop < Nt:
  start = stop
  stop += randint();
  x[start] = any();
np.cumsum(x, out=x)
```

This applies to both the first and second loop.
The `(x2, y2)` are more easily vectorized because the increments do not depend on the previous values
The `(x2, y2)` still require a while loop, but each iteration can be vectorized.

The final result is like this

```py
def ctrw_ens2d_vectorized(sig,tau,sig2,tau2,alpha,xmax,Nens,Nt=1000,dt=1.0):
    # first define the array for time
    T = np.arange(0,Nt,1)*dt

    # generate at least Nt random time increments based on Poisson 
    # distribution (you will use only less than that)
    trand = np.random.exponential(tau, (2*Nt,Nens,1))
    xrand = np.random.normal(0.0,sig,(2*Nt,Nens,2))
    Xdist = np.random.lognormal(-1,0.9,(Nens))
    Xdist = np.clip(Xdist,2*sig,12*sig)

    trand2 = np.random.exponential(tau2, (2*Nt,Nens,1)).astype(np.int64)
    xrand2 = np.random.normal(0.0,sig2,(2*Nt,Nens,2))


    #make a zero array of trajectory
    x1 = np.zeros((Nt,Nens))
    x2 = np.zeros((Nt,Nens))
    y1 = np.zeros((Nt,Nens))
    y2 = np.zeros((Nt,Nens))
    
    #randomly add jumps in between, at later stage
    stop = 1 + np.cumsum(trand2[:,:,0], axis=0)
    # vectorize the indices
    I, J = np.indices(stop.shape)
    m = stop < Nt # Vectorized loop stopping condition
    I = I[m]; J = J[m]; # indices only for the executed iterations
    # update x
    x2[stop[I,J], J] = xrand2[I,J,0]
    y2[stop[I,J], J] = xrand2[I,J,1]
    np.cumsum(x2, axis=0, out=x2)
    np.cumsum(y2, axis=0, out=y2)
    
    
    # this part is more complicated and I vectorized on axis 1
    stop = np.zeros(Nens, dtype=np.int64)
    start = np.zeros(Nens, dtype=np.int64)
    k = np.arange(Nens)
    i = 0
    zx1 = np.zeros_like(x1[0])
    zy1 = np.zeros_like(y1[0])
    assert(np.all(trand > 0))
    m = k
    i = 0
    while np.any(stop < Nt):
        start[:] = stop;
        stop[m] += trand[i,m,0].astype(np.int64)
        m = k[stop < Nt];
        r1 = np.sqrt(zx1[m]**2 + zy1[m]**2)
        rr = np.linalg.norm(xrand[i,m,:],axis=-1) # axis requires numpy 1.8
        
        tx = (1-(abs((r1+rr)/(Xdist[m]))).astype(np.int64))* xrand[i,m,0] \
                - (abs((r1+rr)/(Xdist[m]))).astype(np.int64)* \
                 np.sign(zx1[m]/xrand[i,m,0])* xrand[i,m,0]
        ty = (1-(abs((r1+rr)/(Xdist[m]))).astype(np.int64))* xrand[i,m,1] \
                - (abs((r1+rr)/(Xdist[m]))).astype(np.int64)* \
                 np.sign(zy1[m]/xrand[i,m,1])* xrand[i,m,1] 
        zx1[m] += tx[:] * (start[m] < stop[m])
        zy1[m] += ty[:] * (start[m] < stop[m])
    
        x1[start[m],m] = tx[:]
        y1[start[m],m] = ty[:]   
        i += 1
    
    np.cumsum(x1, axis=0, out=x1)
    np.cumsum(y1, axis=0, out=y1)
    
    return T, (x1+x2), (y1+y2)
```

This runs ~8x faster than the original code here.